# Exposing SQL Server 2000 to the Internet safely

Tags: sql-server, port, sql-server-2000

I've got a SQL Server 2000 box that I'd like to put on "the Internet" so that developers could connect remotely without VPN access.

What's the safest way to do so? It might be temporary, e.g. every once in a while, but it's definitely necessary.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - don't do this.

Long answer:

Install good firewall on the box.

Install and run [ssh server](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) on it.

Open only the ssh port.

Your devs can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or any other ssh client to ["tunnel"](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html) the sql port over the ssh connection.

Comment: If you had static IP's for the developers, couldn't you just make exceptions for them in the firewall and give them access?

Comment: That's actually an interesting approach - depending on the firewall, it could even be setup with some kind of web portal so developers could use a login to update their "allowed" IP. But at the end of the day isn't it just easier to use VPN (or ssh, same diff) instead of trying to roll your own way?

Comment: IP addresses can be spoofed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing), so relaying only on this type of protection is not good.

Answer (score 1):

The SAFE thing to do is put it behind a VPN.

Seriously, why would you even consider such a risk?

Answer (score 0):

Read DannySmurf's answer. If security threat is not your highest concern, then try [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/home.asp?lang=en) at least.

Answer (score 0):

First option, I agree, "don't".

Second option, create a web front end on the exposed box and leave sql non-exposed.

Third option, if you must expose the sql box then mandate asymetric key encryption with all clients, deny all other connections, log clients and review connectivity logs with alerts for clients not matching allowed connection specs (stored in an encrypted table on an internally non-exposed server). Be prepared for some enlightening hacker techniques sure to surprise.

-Alek

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally left an SQl Server (port 1433) open on the net for a while, and once I realized it, I was getting something like 100,000 hits per hour with some sort of automated programs (coming from an army of IP's I believe), trying to break into the server.

Luckily I used very long and complicated passwords...and don't believe I was ever compromised.