# Looking to create a Client-Side Application (WPF) to perform CRUD operations on remote data

Tags: .net, wpf, sql-server, wcf

I'm being handed a project to develop an application I'm thoroughly excited about. The problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to implement one specific requirement.

The application needs to be a client-side application (so I'm using WPF to develop it) and needs to perform CRUD operations to a remote server (so others can also access this data). The main hitch I'm stuck on is that this client application will not only be run from a specific network, but one of the core users will be using it from home as well. I'm not sure how to expose the data to the internet securely.

I was originally developing the app using just LINQ 2 SQL, and imagining that I would simply forward ports to a dedicated machine running SQL Server, but that's probably a horrendous idea. Doing some research, it looks like I'm *supposed* to use WCF to create a service then run that on a machine - and have the WPF client applications use that instead.

That feels like a bit of extra work here, especially since I'm using this project to *learn* WPF. I've not even *looked into* WCF yet. Do I have another alternative? Is my original concept of just exposing the SQL Server to the internet *really all that bad*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my original concept of just exposing the SQL Server to the internet really all that bad?

Yes. There are [many](https://serverfault.com/a/84558/95966) [caveats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11804/8409) and you simply [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425812/266143) (I wanted to link every word in that sentence to another source, but you catch my drift).

WCF is definitely the way to go here, since it has [lots of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx) to [secure it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362.aspx) and is easily [consumed from within WPF](http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/).

While exposing the database and accessing it directly seems like the easiest solution, that's hardly ever the best one. You will have to learn a few new techniques, but you'll benefit from it on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree that you should avoid exposing your database to the internet... it's like leaving a baby alone in the woods overnight (there are creatures on the prowl for sport and profit).

You do have a few options though.  For one, if the company has a network admin, you might consider getting a VPN set up.  That way employees could connect directly to the SQL Server from home, inside the firewall.

Failing that, I think WCF with Linq-to-SQL isn't a bad option.  I built an application with those two, and they work pretty well together-- I had the Linq-to-SQL table entities themselves as the WCF data contract.  One thing I would recommend is to choose a simple design pattern for your CRUD operations, and stick to it as much as possible-- the repository pattern with Load, Find, InsertOrUpdate, and Save.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different angles on this question, but if I am understanding what you are asking...

To resolve your remote user issue: SQL Server can be securely configured to be exposed to the internet for a software as a service application to connect to. Or you could have the remote user VPN into the network that the SQL server resides on.

For a development approach I would suggest MVVM. It works great with WPF and will allow you to learn WPF first with your own custom data layer. Then when you're comfortable you can refactor to use WCF and deliver a quality app.

Answer (score 0):

why not use WCF Data Services - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772(v=vs.103).aspx . If you need it to be secure then see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284.aspx